# Netlify Page Not Found/White Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, netlify

I have been trying to figure out Netlify redirects. My Netlify app is at this link (**however this is a blockchain application and requires that you have metamask, so I will try to explain my problem so that you don't have to install it to actually answer my question**): rekt.netlify.app

I have two main problems:

1. I have already tried the whole _redirects file with `/* /index.html 200` in it. This works when I go to rekt.netlify.app/games and refresh, it will actually come back to that page. That's good. The issue is when I then go to rekt.netlify.app/games/Valorant for example, it will be a white page on refresh, and I cannot figure out why. In my react application, I have react router set up so the path is `path="/games/:game"`

I went to the Networks tab in the google inspect and I found that this was the request URL when I refresh the page on /games/Valorant: `https://rekt.netlify.app/games/static/css/2.80dce9aa.chunk.css`
As you can see, the issue is probably something to do with that /games/ comes before /static/ in the URL. I'm a beginner so I don't know what that actually means.

2. The second issue I am having is that, the img tags of the games load on the /games page, however, when you click on a specific game and attempt to go to a /games/Valorant for example the image will not load. I believe this is due to a similar problem. I have gone into Network tab of google inspect and when I look at the image being loaded in the /games page, it attempts to GET https://rekt.netlify.app/static/media/league_wallpaper.f5e6bf5f.jpg which works. However, when being loaded in the /games/Valorant page, it attempts to GET https://rekt.netlify.app/games/static/media/league_wallpaper.f5e6bf5f.jpg and this does not work, it's a blank page.

You can notice that the second link there has /games/ in it which I believe is preventing it from getting the image. Potentially the problem here is that anything more than one / in the URL is messing things up? I'm not sure. This is the link to my github project: https://github.com/jacob-tucker/ReKt

Edit: Here are some screenshots that will hopefully help. This first one shows that the request URL is trying to get the image from /games/static (which I don't think makes sense). This is happening on the /games/Valorant page.
[image]

And then here is a screenshot of /games/Valorant trying to load as well after I refresh the page and get a blank white screen (it returns a status code of 200 because I have `/* /index.html 200` in my _redirects file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a the same issue a while ago, I've just added

`"homepage": "https://my-app.netlify.app",`
in package.json and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You are an absolute life saver. This is perfect!!!!

Comment: I'm happy it helped :)